# How to update the Build Agent Manually in Azure DevOps 2020?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, build-agent, tfs-2017, azure-devops-server-2020

We have recently upgraded to Azure DevOps 2020 on our testing environment, previously we had TFS 2017 and then upgraded Azure DevOps 2019 and now to Azure DevOps 2020.

I am facing issue regarding the agents I had configured in the earlier version. They don't see to update when I click on the update agent link.

[image]

I have one agent i.e. POC_2017Agent installed and created with TFS 2017 agent and the last two agents were created and installed with Azure DevOps 2019.
After we upgraded to 2020 all 3 of them are shown as Offline, even when their services on the servers are running\restarted.

How can I upgrade the agents manually, if they are not getting upgraded automatically after clicking on the update Agent link?

I don't want to remove them and reconfigure again.

Comment: Please check the agent log which locates in the `_diag` folder where the agent was installed. The log is supposed giving more information. You can mask the private information and share the log.

Comment: Any update to your issue?

Answer (score 6):

Beginning with Azure DevOps Server 2019, you can configure your server to look for the agent package files on a local disk. This configuration will override the default version that came with the server at the time of its release.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=browser#can-i-update-my-v2-agents-that-are-part-of-an-azure-devops-server-pool